# SwiftUI: is it possible to use ForEach + ContextMenu + if statement?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

(tried on macOS only, but I believe there is the same behaviour on iOS)

> macOS 10.15.2 (19C57); Xcode: 11.3 (11C29)

(question was updated because of I have found new relations in the issue)

I have the following code:

```
List(model.filteredStatus) { status in
    StatusViewRow(status: status, model: self.model)
        .contextMenu{
            Text("menu 1")
            Text("menu 2")
        }
}
```

It's works perfectly.

But in case of I want to use ForEach instead ( no matter why):

```
ForEach(model.filteredStatus) { status in
    StatusViewRow(status: status, model: self.model)
        .contextMenu{
            Text("menu 1")
            Text("menu 2")
        }
}
```

Context menu doesn't appear.

**I have found the reason. Reason was in incorrect work of `ForEach` + `contextMenu` + `if` statement combination!**

ContextMenu doesn't work exactly on part of row inside of the `if` statement. Works well on the ful row with `List` and works only on the toogle row part when I'm using `ForEach`.

Can somebody explain why so?

I have an `if` statement inside of `StatusViewRow` contextMenu doesn't appear on this part:

```
struct StatusViewRow : View {
    @ObservedObject var status : FileStatusViewModel
    @ObservedObject var model : StatusViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TaoToggle(state: status.stageState) { self.status.toggleStageState() }
            // you can replace to just a toogle

// ISSUE START HERE 
            if(model.fileNamesOnly) {
                StyledText(verbatim: status.fileName )
                    .style(.highlight(), ranges: { [$0.lowercased().range(of: model.filterStr.lowercased() )]})
            } 
            else {
                StyledText(verbatim: status.path )
                    .style(.foregroundColor(.gray), ranges: { [$0.range(of: status.fileDir) ] } )
                    .style(.bold(),                 ranges: { [$0.range(of: status.fileName) ] })
                    .style(.highlight(),            ranges: { [$0.lowercased().range(of: model.filterStr.lowercased() )]})
            }           
// ISSUE END HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works on iOS 13.2. Works on macOS 10.15.2. Tested with Xcode 11.2.1. Maybe you have Xcode issue?

Comment: `ForEach` needs to be inside a `List`, `VStack`, `HStack`, `ScrollView` etc. - I guess this might be the problem.

Comment: @Asperi macOS 10.15.2 (19C57); Xcode: Version 11.3 (11C29)

Comment: @LuLuGaGa doesn't work: https://imgur.com/cC53b1m + https://imgur.com/c288NJe and issue still reproduced.

Comment: Found new info and updated question;

Comment: Did my answer help? Consider accepting it as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `ForEach` inside a `List` or [relevant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view_layout_and_presentation).

Any view that contains `Text("...")` needs to be either inside a `VStack`, `HStack`, `ZStack`, etc or a `List`. It won't render otherwise.

> When you create a SwiftUI view, the protocol defines that we need to return “`some View`”. The word “`some`” means that we are dealing with an opaque result type. This is a new feature [added in Swift 5.1](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html). An opaque result type means that we must return one, and only one, of the specified type, in this case something that conforms to the “`View`” protocol.

`ForEach` [conforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) to `Hashable`:

```
struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable
```

...whereas [stacks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack) (`VStack` in this case) conforms to `View`:

```
@frozen struct VStack<Content> where Content : View
```

...and `List` also [conforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) to `View`:

```
struct List<SelectionValue, Content> where SelectionValue : Hashable, Content : View
```

So you need something like this:

```
ForEach (model.filteredStatus) { status in
    VStack { // stack View
        StatusViewRow(status: status, model: self.model)
            .contextMenu {
                Text("Menu 1")
                Text("Menu 2")

            }
    }
}
```

OR:

```
ForEach (model.filteredStatus) { status in
    StatusViewRow(status: status, model: self.model)
        .contextMenu {
            VStack { // stack View
                Text("Menu 1")
                Text("Menu 2")
            }
        }

}
```

OR:

```
List { // List works because it conforms to View
    ForEach (model.filteredStatus) { status in
        StatusViewRow(status: status, model: self.model)
            .contextMenu {
                Text("Menu 1")
                Text("Menu 2")
            }

    }
}
```

This article does a good job of explaining [why](https://www.devfright.com/swiftui-hstack-vstack-zstack-tutorial/) it's necessary.

Comment: wrapping `.contextMenu` content into `VStack` (sample 2 in your answer) doesn't resolve the issue. I have been updated my question with original code, maybe you will be interested.... But with simplified code behaviour is the same.

Comment: Wrapping content of ForEach into HStack aslso didn't fix the issue. Wrapping ForEach into VStack also didn't fix issue.... And all 3 actions in the same time also didn't resolve the issue: https://imgur.com/cC53b1m and https://imgur.com/c288NJe ; Using of List is not solution for me, I'm trying to do not use it.

Comment: I have found the reason, but cannot fix issue. Updated the question.

Comment: but, please, don't delete answer that already exist. If you want to change answer, just add sth, but do not delete those info that is written - may be useful for others. Thanks.